# pseudo selector doesn't work in my case

Tags: html, css

demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/BLZfd/

```
<div class=" icon_col"> <a href="#">
              <div class="someclass">
                  <span class="someclass again"></span>
              </div>
                <p>test</p>
                </a>

</div>
```

I did this

```
.icon_col > p: hover {
    text - decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Your paragraph doesn't have any text decoration; the underline comes from the anchor wrapping it.

Comment: Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BLZfd/11/ (Also your CSS was in the Javascript section)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change it to `a:hover` the reason being that the text-decoration is a default styling of the `a` and not linked `p` element.

```
.icon_col > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You also have some redundant spaces in your code which I removed.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BLZfd/3/)

It's also worth noting that the `>` selector means "direct descendant", so that even if your spacing was proper (no whitespace between the selector, the colon, and the pseudo selector) this rule wouldn't have matched anything since the `<p>` tag was not a direct descendent of `.icon_col`, it was a secondary descendent nested inside the `<a>` tag.

If you really want to target that `<p>` tag, you can use this code:

```
.icon_col > a:hover p {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Note the lack of space between the dash and the words in the selector `text-decoration`, as well as the colon and the selector in `a:hover`. **Whitespace is very important**

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this:

```
.icon_col > a: hover {
   text - decoration: none;
 }
```